# Как правильно, загружать, читать, удалять, редактировать данные в таблицы mysql в qt?

Tags: mysql, qt

Не нашел как правильно, загружать, читать, удалять, редактировать данные в таблицы mysql с использованием qt?
Понимаю что где-то есть но не нашел. А очень охота сделать правильно, чтобы работало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

на сколько я понимаю речь о визуализации?

наиболее гибким и удобным является использование моделей (гуглим QSqlTableModel и QSqlQueryModel).

Минимум кода, максимум возможностей.
например. если БД уже подключена

```
model = new QSqlTableModel();
ui->tableView->setModel(model); // просто назначаете виджету на форме модель данных
model->setTable("VIEW_NOTIFICATIONS"); // для модели достаточно назначить имя таблицы
model->select(); // и сделать выборку. остальное QT сделает за вас
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("N_ID"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("ID")); // Можете также задать заголовки для столбцов
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("N_DATE"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Дата"));
model->setHeaderData(model->fieldIndex("N_TEXT"), Qt::Horizontal, QString::fromLocal8Bit("Текст"));
ui->tableView->setColumnHidden(model->fieldIndex("N_HIDE"),true); // какой-то столбец сделать скрытым
ui->tableView->resizeColumnsToContents();
ui->tableView->resizeRowsToContents();
```

кроме того почитайте про QSqlTableModel::data(const QModelIndex &index, int role = Qt::DisplayRole). Раскраска, выделение цветом, и прочите манипуляции при отображении вас порадуют.

Comment: Tatarincev а как добавить в таблицу данные ?

Comment: это уже через запросы. с помощью QSqlQuery добавляйте в БД. Модели работают уже на уровне БД.

Comment: Как можно растянуть таблицу модели, чтобы она заняла весь виджет tableView ? И как можно добавить свободные поля для ввода данных в mysql?

Comment: чтобы растянуть последний столбец - ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setStretchLastSection(true); а чтобы растягивалось по заданному - ui->tableView->horizontalHeader()->setSectionResizeMode(2, QHeaderView::Stretch);